# MySQL UTF-8 error using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, utf-8

I have a zf2 project that records clients informations in a mysql database.
My DB is configured with `utf8` charset and `utf8_unicode_ci`.

My ZF2 `global.php` is this

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'driver'   => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=atendimento;host=localhost',
        'charset'  => 'utf-8',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories'   => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                      => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

In the browser, when i submit the inputs, it goes to a ZF2 error `"Statement could not be executed"` and next `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3' for column 'column' at row 1`

*Sorry if this question have already been answered, but i didnt find an answer, i hope you can help me.*

Comment: UTF-8 charset name for MySQL is `utf8` not `utf-8`. Besides, I don't know how ZF2 consider charset key but with PDO and for PHP >= 5.3.6, you can directly write: `mysql:dbname=atendimento;host=localhost;charset=utf8`. Also, IMO, with MySQL >= 5.5.3, it would be better to use utf8mb4 charset instead of "old" utf8(mb3).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

my friend helped me

The solution was to set `utf8_encode($data)` before recording, and `utf8_decode($data)` in the view

Answer (score 1):

```
return new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ( array (
                'driver' => 'pdo',
                'dsn' => "mysql:dbname=$config[Dbname];host=$config[host]",
                'username' => $config ['Dbuser'],
                'password' => $config ['Dbpassword'],
                'driver_options' => array(
                        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
        ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct config from global and work for me

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=singclub;host=localhost;',
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => '',
        'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
        ),
    ),
);
```